# Bootstrap 3 Toggable tabs displaying the wrong tab on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm implementing a content tabbed section using Bootstrap 3 and it works fine for almost all resolutions except mobile. For some reason only on mobile devices the default active tab is the last one called "All", but the content it displays comes from the first tab ("Popular").

It works perfect on bigger resolutions like iPad or desktop. In this case the default active tab is the first one called "Popular" and the displayed content is correct.

Could you please help me to figure it out what is the problem?

```
<section class="solution-tabs section-tabs">
    <div class="container no-padding">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="col-sm-3 active"><a href="#tabPopular" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Popular</a></li>
            <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#tabIndustries" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Industries</a></li>
            <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#tabTopics" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Topics</a></li>
            <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#tabAll" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tabPopular">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    Popular tab content<br />
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, est quae quo magnam deserunt facere!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabIndustries">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    Industries tab content<br />
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, corporis obcaecati eos vero aliquam sit?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabTopics">
            <div class="container">
                Topics tab content<br />
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus ratione iusto officiis sint quaerat totam.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabAll">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    All tab content<br />
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, fugit fuga doloremque minima ducimus ratione.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```